# Vue.js: extracting data from a nested object using for...in

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a getter in my vuex module which gets data from a nested object, then check if there is any key match to the string and push these matched objects into an array. ESLint says that `for..in` loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what I want. Its suggests to use `Object.{keys,values,entries}`, and iterate over the resulting array.
How can I refactor this?

```
getUsersData({ users: { data: { users } } }) {
  if (users) {
    const arr = Object.keys(users.stats || {}).map(key => users.stats[key]);
    const str = 'active';
    const newArr = [];
    arr.forEach((el) => {
      const obj = {};
      for (const key in el) {
        if (!key.includes(str)) {
          obj[key] = el[key];
        }
      }
      newArr.push(obj);
    });
    return newArr;
  }
  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question has a partial [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807676/482868) I believe. In fact, ESLint is telling you the exact method(s) to use, which is `Object.keys(el)`, for example.

---

Aside from that, there are a few semi-related things you can refactor...

- `Object.keys(users.stats || {}).map(key => users.stats[key])` is essentially the same as `Object.values(users.stats || {})`.

...as well as unrelated ones:

- Names like `arr`, `el`, `newArr`, `obj`, `key`, and `str` are extremely abstract, and dealing with them in real code forces spending brain cycles on decrypting their meaning instead of understanding the *intent* of the code. In fact, I would hesitate to post a question before renaming the variable into something meaningful. See, the readers don't know the complete structure of the object(s) you're working with and it complicates the review process.
- Unnecessary temporary objects may be avoided, if `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()` and [**other chaining-friendly functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629736/482868) are used together.
- A guarding construction `if (!users) return []` is more idiomatic for JavaScript/TypeScript and reduces the nesting (fewer `{`s and `}`s).

---

The result may look something like this. I'm sorry if I missed something — I don't know how to reliably test that my refactoring went well. Plus, it's a late night in my timezone now, so my brain acts funny. :)

```
getUsersData({ users: { data: { users } } }) {
  if (!users) return [];

  return Object.values(users.stats || {})
    .map((statValues) => {
      Object
        .getOwnPropertyNames(statValues)
        .filter(key => !key.includes('active'))
        .reduce((result, key) => {
          result[key] = statValues[key];
          return result;
        }, {});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely, you gave me very good advise. I changed my code and it still works. :)